# How to modify the httpAddress in WSDL?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, soap, wsdl

the problem almost like this: [ASP.NET Web Service changes port on Invoke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531448/asp-net-web-service-changes-port-on-invoke/1532011#1532011).I try to use the [SoapExtensionReflector](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2005/11/16/493496.aspx) to modify the service address in WSDL,and it works on SaopAddress,but the http address is still nochanging.
the result like this:

```
 - <wsdl:service name="WebService1">
  - <wsdl:port name="WebService1Soap" binding="tns:WebService1Soap">
     <soap:address location="http://I can remove this Port:3821/WebService1.asmx" /> 
    </wsdl:port>
  - <wsdl:port name="WebService1Soap12" binding="tns:WebService1Soap12">
     <soap12:address location="http://I can remove this Port:3821/WebService1.asmx" /> 
    </wsdl:port>
  - <wsdl:port name="WebService1HttpGet" binding="tns:WebService1HttpGet">
     <http:address location="http://localhost:3821/WebService1.asmx" /> 
    </wsdl:port>
  - <wsdl:port name="WebService1HttpPost" binding="tns:WebService1HttpPost">
     <http:address location="http://localhost:3821/WebService1.asmx" /> 
    </wsdl:port>
 </wsdl:service>
```

we can see that the soap location has been changed but the last two http:address location are still Unchanged.

here is my code:

```
  public class OuterPortReflector : SoapExtensionReflector
  {       
    public override void ReflectMethod()
    {            
    }

    public override void ReflectDescription()
    {
        ServiceDescription description = ReflectionContext.ServiceDescription;
        foreach (Service service in description.Services)
        {
            foreach (Port port in service.Ports)
            {
                if (!portsName.ContainsKey(port.Binding.Name))
                {
                    portsName.Add(port.Binding.Name, true);
                }

                foreach (ServiceDescriptionFormatExtension extension in port.Extensions)
                {
                    SoapAddressBinding binding = extension as SoapAddressBinding;
                    if (null != binding)
                    {
                        binding.Location = binding.Location.Replace("http://localhost", "http://I can remove this Port");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        HttpAddressBinding httpBinding = extension as HttpAddressBinding;
                        if (httpBinding != null)
                        {
                            httpBinding.Location = httpBinding.Location.Replace("http://localhost", "http://I can remove this Port");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Soap12AddressBinding soap12Binding = extension as Soap12AddressBinding;
                            if (soap12Binding != null)
                            {
                                soap12Binding.Location = soap12Binding.Location.Replace("http://localhost", "http://I can remove this Port");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }      
}
```

How to deal with this? Is there something wrong with my code?

hope somebady can give me some suggestion or keywords.3Q

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?  I'm having the same problem.

Comment: Having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

```
if (null != binding)
if (httpBinding != null)
if (soap12Binding != null)
```

Can you try using Equals(Object) method defined by this [SoapAddressBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.description.soapaddressbinding) class, instead of comparing it directly with null as string.  For example in your case,use

```
if(!binding.Equals(null))
if(!httpbinding.Equals(null))
if (!soap12Binding.Equals(null))
```

Few platform don't work for direct comparision of string , always try to use Equals() method while comparing string.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could accomplish is to use [`HttpModule`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ihttpmodule?view=netframework-4.8). In intercepts every request and changes the response for WSDL.

```
public class WsdlFixHttpModule : IHttpModule
{
    private static string _webServicesBaseUrl;
    public static WsdlFixHttpModule()
    {
        _webServicesBaseUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("BaseWebServicesUrl");
    }
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.EndRequest += (s, e) => OnEndRequest(s, e);
        context.BeginRequest += (s, e) => OnBeginRequest(s, e);
    }
    private void OnBeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContext httpContext = HttpContext.Current;
        if ((!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_webServicesBaseUrl) & httpContext.Request.RawUrl.EndsWith("YourService.asmx?wsdl", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
            httpContext.Response.Filter = new StreamWatcher(httpContext.Response.Filter);
    }
    private void OnEndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContext httpContext = HttpContext.Current;
        if ((!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_webServicesBaseUrl) & httpContext.Request.RawUrl.EndsWith("YourService.asmx?wsdl", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
        {
            string wsdl = httpContext.Response.Filter.ToString();
            wsdl = Regex.Replace(wsdl, @"(?<=address location="")(.*)(?=\/YourService.asmx"")", _webServicesBaseUrl);
            httpContext.Response.Clear();
            httpContext.Response.Write(wsdl);
            httpContext.Response.End();
        }
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}
```

Here is `StreamWatcher` that is used to read default response.

```
public class StreamWatcher : Stream
{
    private Stream _base;
    private MemoryStream _memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    public StreamWatcher(Stream stream)
    {
        _base = stream;
    }
    public override void Flush()
    {
        _base.Flush();
    }
    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        return _base.Read(buffer, offset, count);
    }
    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        _memoryStream.Write(buffer, offset, count);
        _base.Write(buffer, offset, count);
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(_memoryStream.ToArray());
    }
    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
    public override bool CanSeek
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public override void SetLength(long value)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public override long Length
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
    public override long Position
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        set
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

And `HttpModule` needs to be [registered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22192836/4242590) in the web.config